# Creating Core models and extending on diffrent projects (Linq2SQL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, design-patterns, models

I’m working on several projects that share the same “base”. All of them are using Linq2SQL as the ORM, for those unfamiliar with L2S, 1-n table realtions are expressed as EntitySet and 1-1 are expressed as a property (public OtherTable PropName {get;set;}).

What I’m trying to accomplish is to create one Core project containing models that will be shared across several project. And the projects need to be able to extend those models and create new/ override properties (that will be saved on the db), and the same for methods.

All projects use a Repository Pattern to access the db returning IQuerables or a primitive type. And the DataContext is injected by HttpRequest.

I think it’ll be easier to explain by giving examples.
So my User class in BaseProject.Core would have:
(It’s a pain to add all props as virtual using L2S tool, if I delete the table and drag-and-drop again from the db I will manually have to change them all again)

```
public partial class User
    {
        public virtual Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        public virtual EntitySet<BaseProject.Core.UserData> UserDatas;
        }
public partial class UserData
    {
        public virtual Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Int32 ProcessId { get; set; }
    }
```

And one of the projects that will extend it (CurrentProject.Core):

```
public partial class User : BaseProject.Core.User
    {
        public override Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public override DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        public override EntitySet<CurrentProject.Core.UserData> UserDatas;
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
public partial class UserData : BaseProject.Core.UserData
    {
        public override Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public override Int32 ProcessId { get; set; }
        public string MyNewProp { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a new datacontext (I extended the BaseProject.Core datacontext), and re-dragged the tables to get the new properties for the new user class, I have to set ALL of my properties to override on the dbml to make sure I can use them both on base class methods and the extended class (Instead of marking override I could delete each property on the dbml, but I’m still not sure if it’s the best way to do it).

Of course the idea I proposed above will not work, not even compile (different class on the overridden method).

One of the solutions would be to not relate them at all at the core project, but that will remove my ability to create relations on the base project using the entityset, so I would need to query the db using the repositories instead of the models, but it'll hinder my ability to use something on the core project like:

`dc.User.Where(x=>x.UserDatas.Count(y=>y.ProcessId == 1) == 0)`

So I’m hoping someone could give me some idea or a new starting point on how to create base entities on a core DLL and extend it on several projects.

Thanks for taking the time to read all this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have better luck using Entity framework's code first approach.

Here's a good article on that if you are not familiar : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Havn't worked with it enough to say whether it is possible to have Data objects that extend each other in a object orientated way. I would say that's unconventional though a better approach could be to have a Data access (DAO) layer that could be OO in that it extends from each other. One thing to consider is that in L2SQL there is the limitation that you can't do a query on objects that are from different datacontexts.